# Azure DevOps - How to create new project with organizational policies

Tags: azure-devops

We have a standard project policy that we want to apply to all newly created DevOps projects. Is there a way to create default project policies that get applied to newly created DevOps projects within the UI?

Looks like you may be able to do it via [cli](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-repos-git-configuring-standard-policies-on-repositories/) but we need to have it GUI based.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the policy once for all repos and the newer repos by GUI.

Please enter **Project Settings**--> **Repositories**--> **All Repositories**--> **Policy**

And then you can set the policy for all branches of repositories.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. We already know how to apply policy to all repos in a project. The quest is how can we apply those policies to all of our current and future projects in our organization.

Comment: I think that is not possible and you have to set them one by one under project.